# 5V 2 channel relay for <50V

Tags: switch

I am searching for a power relay to switch between two 24V power supplies. Currently I use two separate 5V relays switched on from the same digital output.

[image]

something like this

[image]

I looked in RS and Mouser but am not able to find anything useful. Since there are footprints available I guess such relays exist and hopefully for my requirements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably better suited for electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I tried a similar question in electronics exchange and it was closed for the same reason

Comment: Hm, interesting, not sure why they wouldn't have taken it. I still think it's off topic for this Stack Exchange though. I am glad you got an answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a DPDT (double pole, double throw) relay. This has a schematic like this:
[image: RT-1-DPDT-8A]

You can find such relays in stock at multiple suppliers, though I highly recommend digikey.
Here's a list of 5V DPDT Power Relays with over 2A:

[Digikey.com - 5V DPDT Relays (through hole)](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/relays/power-relays-over-2-amps/188?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1409=340465&sf=1&FV=72%7C249586%2C675%7C380320%2C1409%7C202417%2C1409%7C228181%2C1409%7C228236%2C1409%7C228243%2C1409%7C228247%2C1409%7C340465%2C1409%7C340495%2C1409%7C340503%2C1409%7C340511%2C1409%7C340512%2C1409%7C405969%2C-8%7C188&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25)

[Mouser.com 5V DPDT](https://www.mouser.ca/Electromechanical/Relays/_/N-5g31Z1yzvvqx?P=1z0x3ypZ1z0x3tdZ1y8q6ai)

Comment: Thank you. Without the right keywords it was hard to find the parts